# Installing Docker into Vagrant VM failed

Tags: ssh, docker, vagrant

I'm using Vagrant and Docker and this problem occurred while i `vagrant up` my machine, it works fine before:

```
==> default: Running provisioner: docker...
    default: Installing Docker (latest) onto machine...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

curl -sSL https://get.docker.io/gpg | apt-key add -

Stdout from the command:

Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to get.docker.io:443
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

do you have any idea what caused this problem? or how to fix it?

Comment: can you share your whole Vagrantfile and the command you are using to start your vm?

Comment: here is my [Vagrantfile](https://github.com/imad-bouhamidi/vagrant-docker-jenkins-jhipster/blob/master/Vagrantfile), and im using `vagrant up` to start the machine. and `vagrant ssh` to connect to the machine.

Comment: If I were you I would make the bootstrap.sh script install docker in your vm. see https://github.com/thomasleveil/vagrant-phusion-docker/blob/master/Vagrantfile

Comment: @Thomasleveil thanks for the advice, but didn't the provisioner automates installing Docker? so why use bootstrap script to install it manually..

Comment: because some months ago when I tried the vagrant docker provisioner I add lots of issues (with sharing folders), so I don't rely on vagrant anymore regarding docker

Answer (score 0):

As in [curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection](http://blogs.agilefaqs.com/2013/11/25/curl-35-unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection/), you can try and debug it with:

```
curl -v https://get.docker.io/gpg
```

In the article, it was an access issue:

> I noticed that it was connecting on iPV6 address. I was not sure if our PG server supported iPV6.
>
> Looking at Curl’s man pages, I saw an option to resolve the domain name to IPv4 address. When I tried:

```
curl -v -4 https://my.pg.server
```

> It worked.

Comment: I doubt the OP controls that command which comes from his vagrant docker provider. I guess the fix is to make in the vagrant software :/

Comment: @Thomasleveil but the OP can still execute manually that command, no? Just for test.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue using 1.6.5 and found that it has [been fixed in the Vagrant](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4569). 1.7.2 worked for me. Oddly I had setup a new VM a month ago without running into the issue, maybe Docker has gone back and forth with SSL.